# Convert INT to BIT

Tags: sql-server, int, bit

I tried below query

```
DECLARE @Input INT = 300
DECLARE @Ouput TINYINT

SET @Ouput = @Input
SELECT @Ouput
```

While execute the above statement, I received the following error.

> **Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = 300.**

The input value exceeds the limit, so the error is displayed.

*I tried another query*

```
DECLARE @Input INT = 300
DECLARE @Ouput BIT

SET @Ouput = @Input
SELECT @Ouput
```

When I execute the statement, I really wondered, **it doesn't show any error**. If the input value `<> 0` (negative or positive), the output value always `1`.

Comment: Why do you need to convert BIT to INT mabey there is an other way to solve your problem. You can switch the behavior: `SELECT CONVERT(BIT,CASE @Input WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Actually wats the Question ?I cant clearly got ur question moto ..

Comment: @sarathkumar Why `> 1` value doesn't show any error for `BIT` datatype conversion? What is the conversion functionality behind it? How it is different from other conversion (like INT to TINYINT)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177603.aspx)

Sqlserver have power or say try to convert value implicitly as your input and output type without using cast or convert function, if you not specify any.

When the conversion error comes in default logic or scenerio, it give the specific type cast error.

[So your tiny int and int length is differ, 300 is not fit in tiny int. Tiny int allow max at 255 value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187745.aspx)

[Here is implicit & explicit convertion chart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You receive Arithmetic overflow on setting `int` value to `tinyint` because the range of value of `int` is larger than `tinyint` (you know. **"tiny"**(in small voice)).

Anf if you use `bit` which only have a value of `O` or `1` , basic in Computer fundamentals , and I think the value you get is 1 because it has a value, if none, you'll get 0.