# Casting INT to bit in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What would happen if I cast an `INT` to a `BIT` when `INT` value is 0 and `INT` value is different from 0?

Like:

```
SELECT CAST (0 AS bit)
```

or

```
SELECT CAST (10 AS bit)
```

Comment: Did you consider reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177603.aspx)? "Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1."

Comment: Minimal research??? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24730636/5089204

Answer (score 7):

Simply try it out:

```
SELECT CAST (10 AS bit) AS a, CAST (0 AS bit) AS b
```

returns:

```
a | b
==+==
1 | 0
```

This means 0 remains the same, whereas *all other integer values* are converted to 1.

Comment: I would changed _"values greater than 1"_ to _non-zero values_, because of negative integers are also converted to True.

Comment: @i-one Yes this is correct. Edited the post.